# Using Arduino to allow continuous servo to go in the opposite direction

Tags: servo, adafruit, software, continuous-servo

For my project I am using 6 continuous servos connected to an Adafruit Servo Shield. To run them I use
`pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 1000)`
and then set a delay to run them for how long i’d like to, then run
`pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 0)`
to stop it.

I would like to run the servo in the opposite direction. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably already know that [continuous servos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_(radio_control)#Continuous-rotation_servos) are different to other hobbyist servos in that they rotate freely, and the [PWM signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_control) is used to control speed and direction of rotation.

The specific model of servo you're using is important and you'll need to refer to the datasheet to find out its details. Particulalry the servo's minimum (typically clockwise rotation); mid-point (neutral / no rotation); maximim (usually counter clockwise rotation) PWM pulsewidths. The mid-point is often set by a PWM pulsewidth of 1500 microseconds, but this can vary and it pays to check.

The [library](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-slash-servo-shield/library-reference) you referenced does implement a setPWM() function as you mentioned, however you'll note that it works in a range of *ticks* from 0 to 4095. The two parameter values set when to turn the PWM pulse on and off expressed as values from 0 to 4095. To use this function you'll need to map these parameters to produce the PWM signal the servo is expecting.

I recommend an alternative, using the **writeMicroseconds()** function of the same library, which accepts a value in microseconds for which the PWM signal will be high. You'll be able to obtain these directly from the datasheet.

In your question you mention using a PWM of approximately 25% duty cycle (1000/4095) for ON. This is likely much longer than the desired maximum for your servo which if it is 2000 microseconds, might need a value something like 430 (/4095). Similarly you mentioned a zero pulse to achieve a stop. I think this library uses zero as a special case for no PWM pulse. You said this generates a stop condition for your servos, but finding the neutral value may be better.

Rather than figuring out the maths for setPWM() to turn on and off the PWM pulse, the writeMicroseconds() function may be easier.

You'll need to check datasheets for your servos but a value of 1500 microseconds should be near neutral / no rotation. Decreasing values less than this should generate increasing speed clockwise. Increasing values greater than neutral should generate increasing speed counter clockwise.