# Using pyFirmata with a 360° servo; how do I stop it?

Tags: programming, python, continuous-servo

I am testing out pyFirmata. I have a 360° servo, and know how to change its direction, but I dont't know how to stop it.

What command, like `servo.write()`, would work to make it stop moving until prompted to move again?

Comment: loop through all possible values

Comment: The "angle" is the speed, so set it to the angle that means 'don't move' - i.e., the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check datasheets for your servos but a PWM value of 1500 microseconds would generally be near neutral / no rotation. Decreasing values less than this should generate increasing speed clockwise. Increasing values greater than neutral should generate increasing speed counter clockwise.

See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/88650/71575